# Cutting a string after nth occurrence of a newline (Performance)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I'm currently trying to find an efficient way of slicing newlines inside of div.
I can use whatever anyone recommends as long as it's efficient and dosen't require any javascript framework but JQuery.

I made the following working prototype but I don't know how efficient it is compared to other methods.
[image: JSFiddle]

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Lines').on('change', function(){
      $('#Entry').change()
    });
    
    $('#Entry').on('change', function(){
      var _a = $(this).val(),
      _d = '\n',
      _s = $('#Lines').val(),
      _t = _a.split(_d).slice(0, _s),
      _r = _t.join(_d);

      $('#Original > div.Data').text(_a);
      $('#Modified > div.Data').text(_r);
    });
    
    $('#Entry').val('1 Line\n2 Line\n3 Line\n4 Line\n5 Line\n6 Line\n7 Line\n8 Line\n9 Line\n10 Line').change();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.Data {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.Title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#Original,
#Modified,
#Entry,
.input{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
}

.border-box {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='input'>
    NUMBER OF NEW LINES TO SLICE:
  <input type="number" name="Lines" id="Lines" value='2'>
  </div>
  <div class='w-100'>
    <textarea id="Entry" class="w-100 border-box" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>

<div id='Modified'>
  <div class='Title'>Modified</div>
  <br/>
  <div class='Data'></div>
</div>

<br/>

<div id='Original'>
  <div class='Title'>Original</div>
  </br>
  <div class='Data'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you test efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think fastest code would be to avoid extra operations like string split/join or regular expressions. You can find \n using indexOf, take index of last \n you are interested and do single .slice() call. If you find less \n characters that you require, then just return full string.

```
function splitLine(str, countLines) {
    if (!str) {
        return str; 
    }
    if (countLines <= 0) {
        return '';
    }
    let nlIndex = -1;
    let newLinesFound = 0;
    while(newLinesFound < countLines) {
        let nextIndex = str.indexOf('\n', nlIndex + 1);
        if (nextIndex === -1) {
            return str;
        }
        nlIndex = nextIndex;
        newLinesFound++;
    }
    return str.slice(0, nlIndex);
}
```

Comment: I was looking into the indexOf too but forgot to add that + 1. I think this is the most efficient way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RegExp`:

```
let numberOfLines = 3;

let lines = `1 Line
2 Line
3 Line
4 Line
5 Line
6 Line
7 Line
8 Line
9 Line
10 Line`;

let splitter = new RegExp(`(.*?\n){${numberOfLines}}`);

let matches = splitter.exec(lines);

if (matches)  console.log(`Lines splited: ${matches[0]}`);
```

Output:

```
Lines splitted: 1 Line
2 Line
3 Line
```

If there’s any pattern that starts with something and ends with `\n` that gets repeated `numberOfLines` times,  `matches[0]` will be that string.

Implementing your code would look like

```
(function($) { 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Entry, #Original > div.Data').text(`1 Line
2 Line
3 Line
4 Line
5 Line
6 Line
7 Line
8 Line
9 Line
10 Line`);

        $('#Lines, #Entry').on('change', function() {
        var numberOfLines = $('#Lines').val();
        var newModifiedText;

        var splitter = new RegExp(`(.*?\n){${numberOfLines}}`);

        var matches = splitter.exec($('#Entry').val());
        if (!matches) {
            newModifiedText = "Not enough lines to be splitted in the 'entries' textbox!";
        } else {
          newModifiedText = matches[0];
        }

        $('#Modified > div.Data').text(newModifiedText);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```